# How do I pass a Joda DateTime object as the message body of an HTTP POST to a Jersey REST endpoint?

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jodatime, moxy

I would like to pass a org.joda.time.DateTime as the message body of a json POST to a Jersey endpoint.  My Jersey uses MOXy.  I've created a custom XmlAdapter to do this, but I'm not clear on how to wire up this adapter.  The examples I've found for custom adapters use annotations on the object to be posted, which I cannot do (I can't place an annotation on the DateTime class, since I can't manipulate its source code).

I'm using the Jersey-test framework to test this.

My Jersey Endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("/{memberId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResultBean recordDate(@PathParam("memberId") Long memberId, DateTime dateTime) {
    // TODO stuff happens
    return new ResultBean(memberId, dateTime);
}
```

My Jersey Test:

```
public class FooEndpointImplTest extends JerseyTest {

@Test
public void testWithDate() {
    Long memberId = 1L;
        DateTime date = new DateTime();
        Entity<DateTime> dateEntity = Entity.json(date);
        ResultBean result = target(
                "/" + memberId)
                .request().post(dateEntity, ResultBean.class);
        assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

And my adapter:

```
package foo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class DateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {

    @Override
    public DateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        Long millis = Long.parseLong(v);
        return new DateTime(millis);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(DateTime v) throws Exception {
        return Long.toString(v.getMillis());
    }

}
```

When I run this test as is, I get a 500 error.

Comment: What's the error? Could you show us the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

First things first: You will need a `MessageBodyReader/Writer` for joda DateTime.

It looks like POST of a JSON-serialised DateTime will not work without some adjustments. A Gson serialized DateTime will look like:

```
{ "iMillis": 1414507195233,
  "iChronology": {
    "iBase": {
        "iBase": {
            ...
        },
        "iParam": {
            ...
        }}}}
```

If you try to deserialize it again with Gson, Gson will fail, because `org.joda.time.Chronology`-> `iChronology` does not have a *default-non-arg constructor*, which Gson needs to deserialize the object. Afaig, you will end up in such problems while deserializing DateTime with any standard deserializer.

So I've ended up with creating MessageBodyReader/Writer based on [FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda)

**Reader:**

```java
// ...
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;

@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JodaTimeBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<DateTime> {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JodaTimeBodyReader() {
        mapper.registerModule( new JodaModule());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == DateTime.class;
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime readFrom(Class<DateTime> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(entityStream, DateTime.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ProcessingException("Error deserializing a org.joda.time.DateTime.", e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Writer:**

```java
// ...
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;

@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JodaTimeBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<DateTime> {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JodaTimeBodyWriter() {
        mapper.registerModule( new JodaModule());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == DateTime.class;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(DateTime t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // deprecated by JAX-RS 2.0 and ignored by Jersey runtime
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(DateTime t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
            entityStream.write( mapper.writeValueAsBytes(t));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ProcessingException("Error serializing a org.joda.time.DateTime to the output stream", e);
        }
    }

}
```

*Both registered in ResourceConfig.*

The Writer will respond with 1414507195233 (yap, not JSON) and if you POST this back to your resource, you will get a valid DateTime.

If you get a JSON as like my example above, you could now upgrade the Reader to parse the JSON for iMillis and use the Long value. For TimeZone you could do the same and use `dateTime.withZone(...)` to set value.

Maven dependencies I've used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

*Jersey 2.12*

Hope this was somehow helpful.

Comment: Jackson and MOXy are 2 different JSON providers.

Comment: I don't see your point. The question was how to pass, not how to pass with moxy.

Comment: Your solution will work, however, it requires Jackson while the OP wrote "My Jersey uses MOXy".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
@POST
@Path("/{memberId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResultBean recordDate(@PathParam("memberId") Long memberId, DateTime dateTime) {
    // TODO stuff happens
    return new ResultBean(memberId, dateTime);
}
```

You could do:

```
@POST
@Path("/{memberId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResultBean recordDate(@PathParam("memberId") Long memberId, DateTimeWrapper dateTimeWrapper) {
    // TODO stuff happens
    return new ResultBean(memberId, dateTime);
}
```

Where `DateTimeWrapper` looks like.  Since the `DateTime` object is now a property and not top level the `XmlAdapter` will apply.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DateTimeWrapper {

    @XmlValue
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(YourDateTimeAdapter.class)
    private DateTime value;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Blaise, this certainly would work.  I was hoping to find a way of doing it without adding any sort of wrapper.  Given that I couldn't find a way to do it with just config, this is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: @MarkS - You could write your own `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` but you would need to do the JSON processing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Spring @DateTimeFormat -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html

Never tried this with a body, but it works with params ...

Your call would look something like

```
    public ResultBean recordDate(
    @PathParam("memberId") Long memberId, 
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) DateTime dateTime) {...}
```